# EmberJS + Timepicker

Tags: jquery, ember.js, bootstrap-datetimepicker

So I've been struggling to create some sort of time selector for my Ember application. It seems theres a lot of ember date pickers out there but I need to be able to set time for a model and save it. My only problem is figuring out how to display a selector of different times. I've tried importing jquery timepicker's and making a view but that didn't work out too well after several hours, and none of the addons for ember have timepicker settings in them. What is the best way to go about it and can someone provide an example of what a simple timpicker would look like.

Comment: This question will certainly be closed unless you make it more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a number of time pickers in form of Ember addons:

- [ember-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-bootstrap-datetimepicker) ([demo](http://plusacht.github.io/ember-bootstrap-datetimepicker/))
- [ember-time-input](https://github.com/bdvholmes/ember-time-input)
- [ember-cli-smalot-datetimepicket](https://github.com/JohnnyBushy/ember-cli-smalot-datetimepicket) (WIP)
- [ui-calendar](https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-calendar) ([demo](http://development.ui-calendar.divshot.io/mini-datetime-component))
- [ember-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/plusacht/ember-bootstrap-datetimepicker) ([demo](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#inline) of the underlying jQuery addon)

Don't forget to star the one you'll end up using in your project.

Implementing your own time picker is also possible. But you'll have to ask a specific question to request help with your implementation.

Comment: There is another one: https://github.com/btecu/ember-cli-bootstrap-datetimepicker